# how to kill Activity B when coming from Activity C to Activity A in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm a beginner in android app development. I've developed an app which has 5 Activities: (i.e. Activity - `MainActivity, B, C, D, E`).

when the user opens the app the `MainActivity` will firedm and takes inputs from the user. Upon clicking a button, the user will taken to `Activity B`.

There are 3 buttons in `Activity B` which takes user to 3 different activities:

(i.e. button-1 --> `Activity C`, button-2 --> `Activity D`, Button-3 --> `Activity E`).

after going into any of these 3 Activities (i.e. `C`,`D`,`E`), on pressing back button, the user will be taken back to Activity B. and whichever Activity among `C`,`D`,`E` the user came from will be finished.

If any Alert dialog is displayed in these 3 Activities, upon clicking on `"OK"` in the dialog, the user will be taken back directly to `MainActivity` to take fresh inputs from the user. and the cycle continues again.and also if the user pressed back button when `Activity B` is active, then the user will be taken to `MainActivity`.

when the user press back button in `MainActivity`, a dialog box appears asking if the user wants to exit from the app. upon clicking on "Yes" the app should finish all the activities and close the app.

but what happening is when the user click on `"yes"` the MainActivity is finishing but the `Activity B` is appearing on top again. as it is in the stack, and pressing back button when on `Activity B` will take user to `MainActivity`. a number of times the user navigates back n forth through `Activity B`, that many times the Activity B is coming up when the User clicks on `"Yes"` in the dialog box.

I don't know how to close the app by finishing the activities without affecting the navigation between the activities as there is also a flow of data among those activities (mainly `Activity B`). I've tried using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but it didn't work. The Activity B is still coming up.

Please help me resolve this problem without interrupting the navigation or data flow.

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Are you sure, you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: Please show code of the `AlertDialog` that you pop up in `onBackPressed()` of `MainActivity`.

Comment: this is in MainActivity : @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure, you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();

    }

Comment: this is in Activity B (i.e. Dashboard.java) public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(Dashboard.this,MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
        Dashboard.this.finish();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click `OK` in Activity C,D,E which is meant to take you to the `main activity` while skipping `Activity B`, then you should specify flag

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

I think that should work.

If that actually doesn't work (I'd be surprised), a possible alternative is using `startActivityForResult()` in Activity `B`, to which you'd write a result handling

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == 1) {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

And in Activity C, when you click OK button;

```
this.setResult(1);
finish();
```

Comment: Then go with the second one... although I find that rather odd.

Comment: it worked , thank you very much , I've been struggling to resolve it from a couple of days.. and now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**you may use:**
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. 
(For Example)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

To clear all previous activitys(s) and start a new one.

and check if `exit=true` `finish()` the current one.

**you can also use:** `android:noHistory="true"` in your activity Tag in the Manifest.xml

Note: this will keep no history it means that after you open another activity the previous one will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all activities you can use `finishAffinity()` 
if you are targeting 16 and 16+. For below 16 flags

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Can be used.
The `finishAffinity()` will finish all the activity no matter how many are there below in the task stack.
if you don't want to have an `Activity` visible if you comeback from another `Activity` you can finish it when you start the another.