# OnBackButton pressed Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have 3 Activities A, B, and C.

A is the home activity and B is its child and C is its child.

When I go to Activity C and return to A by pressing back button it gets proper navigation. But after this, if I press back button again to exit the app, it goes back to Activity B instead of exiting the app.

I have finished the Activity B `onBackpressed` override.

And I have implemented dynamic fragments on Activity B is that causes this problem.

I can't find out why this happens. Does Anyone have an answer?

Comment: **finish()** previous Activity if you do not want it to appear on **onBackPressed()**.

Comment: i have done it on Activity B but it again comes..

Comment: Post your code then .

Comment: Could you please share your code

Comment: Possibly your solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624518/how-to-kill-activity-b-when-coming-from-activity-c-to-activity-a-in-android

Comment: thanks i will ckeck

Answer (score 1):

You can use `finish()` or `finishAffinity()` to end that activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B.b.finish();
```

Explanation : 
Declare this in B Activity :

```
private static B(classname) b(some name);
```

Call this in which class do you  finish B Activity :

```
B.b.finish();
```